# How to deploy the web application project in Wso2 Das(Data Analytics Server) server

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I am in New Wso2 server,How to Deploy the Web Application in wso2 Data Analytics Server..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the web application to

```
<DAS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps
```

folder

Comment: Restart is not really required.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the information :)

Comment: How to View The Application in browser After deploying the Webapplication

Comment: @villa: https://localhost:9443/webapp-name is the way to go

Comment: @lakshman Thanks.Application is working fine

Comment: @villa: If answer suit for you be kind enough to mark this as answer :)